# Error in Vue2 Component Method Yet Works When Called From the Console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Bootstrap modal that shows itself on this Vue method:

```
methods: {
    showAddSongModal() {
        $('#addSongModal').modal('show');
    }
}
```

This works in a project where the method is of the root Vue instance. However, I am now trying to use this modal and method in a Vue component. The method is invoked by `@click="showAddSongModal()` but when it's put inside a component, I get this error on click:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

Otherwise, the page loads without errors in Chrome Dev Tools. And what's more, typing `$('#addSongModal').modal('show');` at the console behaves like it should -- the modal works!

Thus far, I checked:

1. jQuery is called but once.
2. jQuery, Bootstrap, Vue, Axios, et al. are called before my Vue components.

The fact that `@click="showAddSongModal()` works from the console should validate my build process, right?

Why does this modal and method work from a root Vue instance but cause the `Uncaught TypeError` when placed inside a Vue component?

My project has the Vue components, each in a component file and included like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="song-table">
        <song-modal-form></song-modal-form>
        <div class="table-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mt-3">
            <form id="search" class="">
                Search <input name="query" v-model="filterKey"> 
            </form>
 ....
html continues

<script>
    import SongModalForm from './SongModalForm.vue';

    export default {

        components: {
            SongModalForm
        },
 ....
        methods: {
            showAddSongModal() {
                    console.log('HELP!');
                    $('#addSongModal').modal('show');
            },
  ....
</script>
```

[This Pen shows the scenario, a parent component calling the child component with the modal.](http://codepen.io/stwilson/pen/bqEoXL)

The pen works, but in my actual project `$('#addSongModal').modal('show');` is only working from the console and not from the component:
[image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem in a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: Working version:  http://codepen.io/stwilson/pen/wJMrpd

Comment: What is it you're putting in the component? The button? The modal? Both?

Comment: Both.  Here is the component version so far: http://codepen.io/stwilson/pen/bqEoXL

Comment: I see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Laravel 5.4.14 framework in this project.  Using webpack, I was mixing together .js files like this:

- .js files required  site-wide (JQuery, Bootstrap, Vue, et al) into one `app.js`
- backend-specific .js files like my Vue instance and specialized scripts into `backend.js`

`app.js` had only the following one line to require bootstrap.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

`bootstrap.js` required (JQuery, Bootstrap, Vue, et al).

`backend.js` looked something like this:

```
import SpecialComponent from './components/SpecialComponent.vue';
import LoginModal from './components/LoginModal.vue';
import RegisterModal from './components/RegisterModal.vue';
import SongTable from './components/SongTable.vue';

Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'wave'
];

const app = new Vue( {
    el: '#app-backend',

    components: {
        SpecialComponent ,
        LoginModal,
        RegisterModal,
        SongTable
    },

    data: {
        currentPath: window.location.pathname
    },
});
```

Then for a backend page, the html called the files like this:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/backend.js"></script>
```

That DID NOT WORK.

Once `require('./bootstrap');` was added to `backend.js` and I dropped `app.js`, the Uncaught TypeError went away.

Answer (score 1):

In components, you can only have one root element in your template. What you need to do is wrap your button and modal in a single div (or some other element) and your component will work.

Change your template to this in your failing codepen.

```
<div>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-3" @click="showAddSongModal()">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="addSongModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" v-text="message"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working version](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GWoOOy).

Comment: Yes, you are right about the wrapping div - a mistake in my codepen.  Good eye!  I cannot quite duplicate my problem yet.  In my actual project, I have the Vue components in their own files and using webpack.  I will ammend my question to show.

Comment: The modal itself is in its own component, which is being called from a parent component table in which it's included.  You asked earlier about what was in the component - the model is in an included child and the button with the calling method is in the parent.  I do have all elements wrapped together in a single div in the parent.

Comment: @STWilson It is puzzling that it would work from the console and not click. How are you including JQuery? Is this hosted somewhere?

Comment: I updated the pen to better represent my scenario and cannot duplicate the error - it works:  http://codepen.io/stwilson/pen/bqEoXL

Comment: I am using the Laravel 5.4 framework.  I have the packages installed and required with node/npm.  Then, `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); window.Tether = require('tether');`  Indeed, I am puzzled too why I can activate the modal from the console and not from the method.

Comment: This may be a shaggy-dog story.  I compiled a fresh install of the framework, copied over my Vue components, and it works.  No errors.